# How to force specific type of HTML tag in the component interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I created an input (type="checkbox") component that accepts children props from the parent

```js
interface CustomCheckboxProps {
  children?: string;
}

const CustomCheckbox = (props: CustomCheckboxProps) => {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>{children}</label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would like to change the color of the children but only in some section (substring). For example a string `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit`, I would like `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` to be in red.

I found the solution by changing the children type into ReactNode and pass a `<p>` with a `<span>` inside and use css to change color of the span text

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <CustomCheckbox>
      <p>
        <span className="text-red-300">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>,
        consectetur adipiscing elit
      </p>
    </CustomCheckbox>
  );
};
```

This works as intended but ReactNode allows all types of HTMLElement such as `<button>` and `<h1>`. Is there a way to enforce the children type to be [`<p>` with `<span>` inside] or [`<p>` and `<span>`] only? I do not want a button or a list inside the label

I tried `HTMLParagraphElement` type but it gives the error: `Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLParagraphElement': align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 274 more.ts(2740)`

I also tried the following:

```
interface Props {
  children?: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>;
}
```

It does accept `<p>` but the problem is that it accept all types of HTMLElement.

Is there a way to enforce the type of HTMLElement? If it is impossible, is there other way to change the color of the text (substring) of type string? Thank you

Note: I used Tailwind CSS in this example hence:

- `className="flex"` -> `style={{ display: flex }}`
- `className="text-red-300"` -> `style={{ color: red }}` //some value of red

Comment: What are you doing that `<div>` is the only valid option? Because div is almost always _not_ the right tag.

Comment: why not wrap each child in a div, if that's really what you wanted? You can use `React.cloneElement` to accomplish this

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I would like to prevent the `<button>`, `<input>`, etc tags.

Comment: That is not an answer, though. What are you actually trying to do that requires you to write an interface that only allows div children, because that's almost _certainly_ not what it should be containing. (lists of divs are a great sign that you're not generating semantic markup, and are instead generating DOM pollution)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, it doesn't have to be only div tag, I just want to know whether can I force the children to be a specific type of HTML tag.

Comment: For example, I create a component that is `<ul>` and want to force its children to be of type `<li>` only. With this, I can use css to change the text color of each `<li>`

Comment: Then you definitely want to change your post to reflect that. Also, that sounds like something you are most definitely not the first person on the planet to ever want: are you sure there are no articles on the web, or even questions on SO about this already? (what did you [search and find](/help/how-to-ask) already?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the question and added more context. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use static type checkers like [Flow](https://flow.org). With Flow, you can do a lot more type checking than the standard prop-types library and it was also developed by Facebook too!

Flow has a special type called React.Element<typeof Component> which forces a specific types of JSX elements like div, span, h1, and so on (intrinsic JSX element) to a component.
Here's an example of how to use this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
children: React.Element<'div'> //children is required
};

function MyComponent(props: Props){
// do some stuff
}
```

For more examples, visit their official [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/) and to add the dependency in your React codebase use [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Comment: It seems that dev are migrating from flow to Typescript, and not recommending to start new project with flow. Also, I need to use TypeScript in my project. Thank you